# Apple News App rendering | UIWebview in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, nsurlcache

I've taken a look at the News App shipped with iOS9, which does great at being agnostic to user content. I know this question may not please SO, because 'unspecific', but bearing in mind that the input is essentially a RSS feed, what's the likelihood to have the rending approach implemented via a UIWebview embedded in a UIViewController?

If yes, and to ensure the app remains snappy, if the images are preloaded and stored in NSURLCache, can a UIWebview natively access that cache?

Cheers
-A